# How to get the date of [(selection)] of primeNg data table. Angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an angular 2 project which uses primeng table wih multiple selection function. The selected value are stored in the [(selection)]. My question is how can I call/use the [(selection)] value in the component.ts. I tried logging the [(selection)] value in the console but getting an error.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="persons" selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedPersons" dataKey="personId">
    <p-header>Excluded Stores</p-header>
    <p-column field="personId" header="person Id" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="personFirstName" header="First Name" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="personLastName" header="Last Name" [sortable]="true"></p-column>                   
</p-dataTable>
<button (click)="showPersonsSelected()"> Show List of person selected </button>
```

in my Component

```
export class SelectclusterComponent{

persons = [];

selectedPersons: person [];

showPersonsSelected(){
 console.log(this.selectedPersons);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You also can use ViewChild to access Datatable class directly in component:

Template:

```
<p-dataTable #tbUsers ...></p-dataTable>
```

Component

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTable } from 'primeng/primeng';

@ViewChild('tbUsers') tbUsers: DataTable;

rowSelected(){
    console.log(this.tbUsers.selection);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add function onRowSelect into tag p-dataTable below:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="persons" selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedPersons" dataKey="personId" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)">
```

In .component.ts get information of selected row below:

```
onRowSelect(event) {
    console.log(`Query selected: ${event.data.orderNumber} - ${event.data.country}`);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `onRowSelected` event as below,

```
<p-dataTable (onRowSelect)="rowSelected($event)" selectionMode="multiple"
          [value]="tableData" [(selection)]="selectedData" 
           dataKey="model" [responsive]="true">
    <p-column field="orderNumber" header="Order Number"></p-column>
    <p-column field="country" header="Country"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

And you have the selected items

```
 rowSelected(event){
    console.log(this.selectedData);
  }
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ID3X0qxXcLnGWYc23kGl?p=preview)

Comment: My bad I'm calling the wrong function in my code. That's why. My code is as is. It's working. But I have a question @Aravind. I like to have the table to a specific number of rows regardless if the data is empty. Lets say I like the displayed rows in the table to be 10 rows minimum even if data from service is empty..

Comment: reach me at fb @ aravind2109 to avoid lengthy conv here

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ you need more help ?

Answer (score 0):

there is an Event Emitter "selectionChange" the event equal
selections value

```
   <p-table
    #dt
    [value]="users"
    [(selection)]="selectedUser"
    dataKey="id"
    selectionMode="multiple"
    [selectionPageOnly]="true"
    (selectionChange)="onSelect($event)"
  >
  </p-table>
```

in ts file

```
 onSelect(selectedUsers: User[]) {
  console.log(selectedUsers);
 }
```